# pd.to_datetime producing "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting quite an unexpected behaviour using pandas' `pd.to_datetime`. My `pd.Series` is as follows:

```
0         2017-01-06 14:37:16
1         2017-01-27 00:00:00
2         2017-01-18 00:00:00
3         2017-01-26 00:00:00
4                        None
                 ...         
454823    2019-10-22 11:20:03
454824                   None
454825    2019-07-11 00:00:00
454826                   None
454827    2019-07-15 00:00:00
Name: colx, Length: 454828, dtype: object
```

And when casting to `datetime` I'm getting:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.colx, errors='coerce')
```

> InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

While this seems to indicate that there are duplicate values in the index, I ran the following tests to check if that was the cause:

```
all(df.colx.index == range(df.colx.shape[0]))
# True

df.index.duplicated().any()
# False
```

So apparently there aren't any duplicate indexes. What could be causing this error?

Comment: Can you slice this dataframe into smaller parts still generating the error?  What is the small you can get and still generate this error?

Comment: @yatu, which version of `pandas` are you running? If < `0.25.0` try specifying `cache=True` in `pd.to_datetime`. I think you have an issue with both `pd.NaT` and `None` being null values in that column, which was fixed with 0.25

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @alollz I'll try tomorrow

Comment: You're completely right @ALollz that just did it. My serius has many `None` and also `pd.NaT`s, and fillning with `np.NaT` solved it. My pandas version is 0.25.2 though. So apparently this is still causing problems.

Comment: Feel free to add as an answer. Otherwise I will. It will be useful to have one here, I'm surprised i found nothing related @ALollz

Comment: This appears to have regressed in pandas v1.2.5 released today (June 22nd, 2021).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The error you are receiving isn't related to your `Index`. It's related to [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/26078) issue which should have been fixed as of `0.25.0`. The issue was related to the following inconsistent handling of multiple `null` types when using `pd.to_datetime`

```
import pandas as pd

pd.core.algorithms.unique([pd.NaT, None])
#array([NaT, None], dtype=object) # That is, `pd.NaT` and `None` are unique

pd.Index([pd.NaT, None]).is_unique
#False   # However, Index.unique considers them duplicated
```

---

The handling of this different behavior should have been fixed with `0.25.0`. If it's still giving you a problem the solution is to ensure you have a **single** representation of `null` values in the column you need to convert. In this case you can `.fillna` with the datetime null value.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.colx.fillna(pd.NaT), errors='coerce')
```

---

```
pd.__version__
#'0.25.0'

pd.to_datetime([pd.NaT, None])
#DatetimeIndex(['NaT', 'NaT'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Upgrading to the current latest Pandas version (1.1.2) did not help, but the work-around you suggested here did solve the problem for me. I guess the bug is not actually fixed or there was a regression.

Comment: It still seems to be an open issues. I just had the problem on Pandas version 1.2.0.
Replacing with pd.NaT worked though. Thanks for the solution here.

Answer (score 3):

## Start from clearing a misunderstanding

I noticed such an error in your check procedure:

Calling `df.index.duplicated().any()` checks only that the **index** has no
duplicates.

To investigate the issue, I created my input file from your data (just 10 data rows):

```
colx
2017-01-06 14:37:16
2017-01-27 00:00:00
2017-01-18 00:00:00
2017-01-26 00:00:00
None
2019-10-22 11:20:03
None
2019-07-11 00:00:00
None
2019-07-15 00:00:00
```

I read it calling *read_csv*, called `df.duplicated().any()` and the
result was **True**, so there **are** duplicates in *colx* column.

Run `df.duplicated()` and you will see that *True* is printed for
rows with index *6* and *8* (second and third instance of *None* string).

Another check: Run `df.info()` and you will get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 1 columns):
colx    10 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 208.0+ bytes
```

This confirms that **no** element has "true" *None* value.
There are only **strings** containing "None".

Another remark: `all(df.colx.index == range(df.colx.shape[0]))` checks
only that the index contains consecutive numbers, which says
**nothing** about the content of *colx*.

## How you read your DataFrame

I suppose your read your DataFrame calling e.g. *read_csv*, without any
conversion, so *colx* column is of *object* (actually *string*) type.

In such case an attempt to call *pd.to_datetime* fails on the first
element containing *None* (a **string**), because it can not be converted
to *datetime*.

## What to do

Try the following approach:

1. When reading the DataFrame, pass *na_values=['None']* parameter.
   It provides that elements containing *None* are not left as strings,
   but are converted to *NaN*s.
2. Print the DataFrame (read from my limited source).
   Instead of *None* (a string) there will be *NaN* - a special case of **float**.
3. Run *df.info()*. This time the printout will be:

   ```
   <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
   RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
   Data columns (total 1 columns):
   colx    7 non-null object
   dtypes: object(1)
   memory usage: 208.0+ bytes
   ```

   Note that there are only **7** non-null values, out of total **10**,
   so the 3 remaining are "true" *None* values, which *Pandas* prints as *NaN*.
4. Run *pd.to_datetime(df.colx)*. This time there should be no error.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error, for me works next:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.colx.astype(str))
```

Comment: I doubt this solves the problem of `None` or `NaN` values.  Have you tested it with data from OP?