# Pandas - No Null values but pd.to_datetime gives “Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index values"?

Tags: pandas, datetime, index-error

#### Sample Data

```
+---------+------------------------+
|         |          date          |
+---------+------------------------+
|       0 | 2020-12-31 00:00:00    |
|       1 |    2020-12-31 00:00:00 |
|       2 |    2020-12-31 00:00:00 |
|       3 |    2020-06-11 00:00:00 |
|       4 |   2020-03-10 00:00:00  |
|  172588 | 2020-03-05 00:00:00    |
|  172589 | 2020-03-05 00:00:00    |
|  172590 | 2020-01-27 00:00:00    |
|  172591 | 2020-01-20 00:00:00    |
| 172592  | 2020-01-07 00:00:00    |
+---------+------------------------+
```

#### Error

> df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"],
> errors="coerce").dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

Produces the following Error:

```
~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    799         cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    800         if not cache_array.empty:
--> 801             result = arg.map(cache_array)
    802         else:
    803             values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   3968         dtype: object
   3969         """
-> 3970         new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
   3971         return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index).__finalize__(
   3972             self, method="map"

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
   1129             values = self._values
   1130 
-> 1131             indexer = mapper.index.get_indexer(values)
   1132             new_values = algorithms.take_1d(mapper._values, indexer)
   1133 

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_indexer(self, target, method, limit, tolerance)
   2984 
   2985         if not self.is_unique:
-> 2986             raise InvalidIndexError(
   2987                 "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"
   2988             )

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

#### What have i tried

> [pd.to_datetime producing "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595395/pd-to-datetime-producing-reindexing-only-valid-with-uniquely-valued-index-objec)
>
> [Resolving Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533706/resolving-reindexing-only-valid-with-uniquely-valued-index-objects)

### Why this is different

1. There are definitely duplicates in the date column, but its not an index
2. There are no null/na values in this column as the first link suggested. So making all NaT/Null/Na values unique does not solve the problem

Comment: What is your pandas version? Do you try upgrade to last one?

Comment: With pandas version 1.1.5, I can't reproduce your error with that `'date'` column.

Comment: Also, if you want to keep a datetime dtype, but with only the date, use `df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], errors="coerce").dt.date`.

Comment: I think the easiest way out could be to reset the dataframe index before applying `pd.to_datetime()`. Try this way: `df.reset_index(inplace = True)`

Comment: Hi all, On pandas version 1.1.5, Have tried each of the methods above and the error persists. I beleive the issue must have to do with how the dataframe object itself is treated prior to this operation being run. In isolation, if i import a csv with these values, the code works fine, but after some processing it doesnt..

Comment: Following the traceback, 
from pandas import Index
Index(ainput_t1).is_monotonic_decreasing 
 returns False even after resetting index

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem,

df with pandas version 1.3.0, a string column who had to be converted to_datetime and when doing so the number of values decreased. I couldnt explain the null values on the converted to_datetime column, they were not null, None, nor NaT in the string column. The problem solved when I added `cache=False` in the `to_datetime`